# How can i remove the white space dynamically getting in anchor tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.6

I am getting About Us through

```
<?php echo ($contents->title); ?>.
```

But I want to convert this to About_us. How can I achieve this? After this clicking on that anchor it showing `About us` in the URL but I want to remove that space between them or change it like About_us.

```
<a  class="smoothscroll" href="#<?php echo ($contents->title); ?>" scroll-to="#para_1">
```

Comment: `echo str_replace(' ','_',$contents->title);` ?

Comment: `trim` ??????????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` to replace all spaces in your string with underscore like below:

```
 <?php $contents->title = str_replace(' ','_',$contents->title); ?>
```

If `$contents->title` contains `About Us` then above code will replace `About Us` with `About_Us`